# Is there any way to eliminate the singular point to solve this integral by hand or by approximations?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis, approximation

$$\int_0^1 (1+(x^{-p}-1)^{1-p})^{\frac{1}{p}}dx, p\in \mathbb{R}, p\ge 1$$
I find that $x=0,1$ are singular points(discontinuous points of this integral), is there a way to eliminate those singular points to make sure that this integral can be calculated by hand or by Taylor approximations. In either cases, what are those steps of calculating the integral?

Comment: What is $p$? Please give more information to make it complete.

Comment: @xbh already fixed it, thanks for reminding.

Comment: Seems that $0$ is not singular here… [I might compute wrong]

Comment: @xbh can you show me how to get the close formula for the integral above?

Comment: Sorry, i am working on it. It is highly impossible that this integral has a closed form.

Comment: Even using special functions, there is more than likely no way to get a closed form (except for $p=2$).

Comment: @ok fine, but is that the only singular points are $x=0,1$?

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici and if we can't find a close formula, can we try the approximations here?