# How to use power series to find the approximate value of this integral function with $p$ as a variable?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, power-series, approximation

$$L(p)=\int_0^{2^{-\frac{1}{p}}}(1+(x^{-p}-1)^{1-p})^{\frac{1}{p}}dx, p\in \mathbb{R}, p\ge 1$$

Parametrize $x$ as $\cos^{\frac{2}{p}}(t)$, then we can find a equivalent form of the integral, namely

$$L(p)=\int_{\frac{\pi}{4}}^{{\frac{\pi}{2}}}(\frac{2}{p})\sin(t)\cos(t)(\cos^{2-2p}(t)+\sin(t)^{2-2p})^{\frac{1}{p}}, p\in \mathbb{R}, p\ge 1$$

How to use power series to find the approximate value of this integral function with $p$ as a variable?

Comment: Are these two questions related? https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2915392/269624

Comment: And this is the third one... Would make sense to combine them https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2912749/269624

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if there's a convenient way to turn this into a power series. The function is rather complicated.

Through the sequence of substitutions I was able to transform the integral to the form:

$$L(p)=\frac{1}{p} \int_0^1 v^{1/p-1}(1+v)^{-1-1/p} (1+v^{p-1})^{1/p}  \mathrm{d} v$$

Since $v \leq 1$, each bracket can be expanded into a binomial series, for example:

$$(1+v^{p-1})^{1/p}=\sum_{k=0}^\infty \binom{1/p}{k} v^{(p-1)k}$$

Now we need to find the integral:

$$ \int_0^1 v^{(p-1)k+1/p-1}(1+v)^{-1-1/p}  \mathrm{d} v$$

This is a very well known Gauss hypergeometric function (see Wikipedia or other sources).

Finally, we have:

> $$L(p)=\sum_{k=0}^\infty \binom{1/p}{k} \frac{1}{p(p-1)k+1} {_2 F_1} \left((p-1)k+\frac{1}{p},1+\frac{1}{p};(p-1)k+\frac{1}{p}+1;-1 \right)$$

What's the point, you may ask? Turns out, the series converges pretty fast. For example, here's the plot for the original integral (blue) vs the approximation with just $\mathbf{5}$ terms (red):

[image]

$$L1(p)=\sum_{k=0}^5 \binom{1/p}{k} \frac{1}{p(p-1)k+1} {_2 F_1} \left((p-1)k+\frac{1}{p},1+\frac{1}{p};(p-1)k+\frac{1}{p}+1;-1 \right)$$